10th Anniversary of Economics SE!
Later this month, Economics SE turns 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community for a whole decade!
Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.
How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer that helped you solve a problem? Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!

Congratulations to Economics on this huge milestone!

The question about why burgers don't cost 5 cents was a little comical, but got some very interesting responses! I still think about that post from time to time.
